# Getting values from checkbox group and adding/removing them from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a form where I have a group of checkboxes.

When click on checkbox, I would get the value of that specific checkbox and add to an Array (I am using the useState hook) and if I uncheck it will remove that element from the array.

That's my code so far:

```js
const ContactUs = () => {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(cities)
  })

  const handleCheck = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setCities([...cities, e.target.value])
    } else {
      removeCities()
    }
  }

  const removeCities = () => {
    setCities(() => cities.splice(DT.length - 1, 1))
  }

  return (
    <Content>
      <form>
        <SectionTitle>Day Tours</SectionTitle>

        <Checkbox
          type="checkbox"
          id="1"
          label="Dublin"
          value="dublin"
          name="dublin"
          onChange={handleCheck}
        />
        <Checkbox
          type="checkbox"
          id="2"
          label="New York"
          value="New York"
          name="new-york"
          onChange={handleCheck}
        />
        <Checkbox
          type="checkbox"
          id="3"
          label="Torino"
          value="Torino"
          name="torino"
          onChange={handleCheck}
        />
      </form>
    </Content>
  )
}
```

I can add it to the array but I can't seem to remove it (or remove the right one).

I tried splice and slice methods but as I don't fully grasp their concept.

Comment: Can edit the post and upload the array to the post? @Yuri_Rech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is `DT` as you haven't shared your whole code, but I think you can approach this in another still functional, declarative way:

Filter out the array so it returns everything that is checked and filters (removes) the unchecked ones:

in your else block:

`setCities(cities.filter(city => city !== e.target.value))`

Filter will always return a new array with the values that match the filter criteria, in this case it would return everything except the `e.target.value`, which is what we want as based on your logic, the else block will execute when it's unchecked.

Comment: Hi, I just updated it DT is actually cities. My code is basically it with two other text inputs. I will check your answer! thanks

Comment: Yeah, I suspected but couldn't be sure. I advise you not to manipulate the initial array. If the state of the checkboxes (checked/not checked) is driven by the `cities` hook (and it should be, rather than an array variable) then just remove it from there whenever it's unchecked. On a state change the component will re-render but now it will re-render without the checked values, and so on. This is (one of the point of React) re-rendering on state change.